# Stopping HTTP requests at JBoss shutdown

Tags: httprequest, jboss5.x, shutdown

Using JBoss 5.1.0 GA.

I have a app with about 100 EJB's and the shut-down process can sometimes be very long. I have noticed that even after I trigger the shut-down process the app can still process HTTP request from users that are still logged-into the web apps.

My question is : Is there any mechanism to stop the HTTP requests once I intercept a server shut-down notification ? 
I would not allow the users to make any HTTP request after the server-shut-down command has been issued.

Thank you